# Stop inner anchor tag function call outer input field function javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an code where i want to stop inner function to stop outer function.

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="policy" formControlName="policy" id="policy" (click)="policySelect()" />
  <label for="policy"> 
  <span *ngFor="let policy of policies">
  <a (click)="policyPopup(policy.policyType)">{{policy}}</a>
  </span>
  </label>
```

i have tried but no use

```
  policyPopup(policy){
event.stopPropagation();}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass event object to click handler and then call stopPropagation on it.

```
 <a (click)="policyPopup($event, policy.policyType)">{{policy}}</a>

policyPopup(event, policy) {
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```